# DRF change url to absolute url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i uploaded some file to server you can see the adress:

and its the resault:

```
 "product_video": [
            {
                "product": 12,
                "name": "backup",
                "file": "/upload/user_1/backup.zip",
                "video_length": null,
                "is_free": false
            },
            {
                "product": 12,
                "name": "backup",
                "file": "/upload/user_1/backup_9um5Gwm.zip",
                "video_length": null,
                "is_free": false
            }
        ]
```

`"file": "/upload/user_1/backup.zip",`

can you please tell me how can i change it to absolute url like:

`localhost:8000/upload/user_1/backup.zip",`

we had some function linke get absolute url in django  i dont about drf

its my serializer class:

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product_ratings = ProductRatingsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    product_video = ProductVideoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.author.first_name + ' ' + obj.author.last_name

    def get_category(self, obj):
        return obj.category.title


    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'product_id',
            'author',
            'title',
            'mini_description',
            'you_learn',
            'you_need',
            'full_description',
            'price',
            'video_level',
            'video_length',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
            'product_ratings',
            'product_video'
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['product_id', 'created_date', 'updated_date', 'author',
                            'product_ratings']

    def validate_title(self, value):
        if self.context['request']._request.method == 'POST':
            qs = Product.objects.filter(title__iexact=value)
            if self.instance:
                qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
            if qs.exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError("this title is already used")
        return value
```

product video serilizer: ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌

```
class ProductVideoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductVideo
        fields = [
            'product',
            'name',
            'file',
            'video_length',
            'is_free',
        ]
```

‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌

Comment: Which is the field name corresponding to the file url?

Comment: i added the missed info  -  file field

Comment: Would you update your question with `ProductVideoSerializer` as well?

Comment: yes post updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField` in your `ProductVideoSerializer` class.

```
class ProductVideoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    file_abs_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ProductVideo
        fields = [
            'product',
            'name',
            'file_abs_url',
            'video_length',
            'is_free',
        ]
    def get_file_abs_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.file.url)
```

Comment: thankyou for answer but i have 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_url'

error

Comment: @moh You have to pass the context to the Serializer.

Answer (score 4):

The URL generation requires a request-context to be passed in to the serializer, like

```
ProductSerializer(context={"request":request})
```

to work, If you use a ViewSet this is done for you. Else the code does not know what to use as a host name, with this in place you can do it manually.

```
file = SerializerMethodField()
def get_file(self, obj):
    return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(obj.file.url)
```